# How to get data from two different table with different columns

Tags: php, mysqli

table1

```
id  | pid   |pdate

1   |ab001  |25/05/2017

2   |ab002  |25/05/2017
```

table2

```
id  |rid    |rdate

1   |cd001  |25/05/2017

2   |cd002  |25/05/2017
```

Output

```
id  |cid    |date

1   |ab001  |25/05/2017

2   |ab002  |25/05/2017

1   |cd001  |25/05/2017

2   |cd002  |25/05/2017
```

Comment: simply join 2 table! whats your question exactly?

Comment: i need mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(SELECT table1.id, table1.pid, table1.pdate FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT table2.id, table2.rid, table2.rdate FROM table2);
```

Comment: You don't need the table name qualifiers though and you need to specify the column names he wants in the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this example:**

```
SELECT id FROM table1 UNION SELECT cid FROM table2;
```

**Output:**

**id     rid**

1        ac22